# NetAddr Dumper output

Tags: perl

I am having issues with my script when trying to use the `NetAddr::IP::Compact` function

```
my $var = new NetAddr::IP '127.0.0.1/8';
print Dumper $var;
```

Output from this is:

```
$VAR1 = bless({
     'addr' => '',
     'isv6' => 0,
     'mask' => '?????????????'
}, 'NetAddr::IP');
```

My questions is why am I not seeing the addr and mask field filled here?

```
Use of uninitialized value in sort at blib/lib/NetAddr/IP.pm (autosplit into blib/lib/auto/NetAddr/IP/compactref.al) line 737.
```

Comment: Did you read the perldoc? Have you tried the example they have on cpan? `print "The address is ", $ip->addr, " with mask ", $ip->mask, "\n" ;` Side note, it's a good idea to make your variable names meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Data::Dumper's default settings are awful.

```
{
   local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
   print Dumper $var;
}
```